# What if in java I override "equals()" but not hashCode()?

Tags: java, object, overriding, equals, hashcode

[Core java programming] says if I overrides Object.equals(), then I should override Object.hashCode() at the same time.

This is quite odd to me, if I don't override hashCode() at the same time, is there any possibility that something wrong could happen in logic?

Would you help to give such an example to indicate?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You'll break `HashSet` and `HashMap` - if equal objects can have different hash codes, they can end up in a `HashSet` twice, which isn't what you want in a `Set`.

Comment: I would have a look at existing posts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java

Comment: Many areas of the Java API have contracts which say that if two object match via `equals()`, then they should have the same hash code.  If you _don't_ override `hashcode()` and enforce this, then the contract would break.

Comment: Check this too :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14608683/java-what-happens-if-hashcode-is-not-overriden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `a.equals(b)` is `true`, `a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()` must also be true. If it's not the case, adding `a` to a `HashSet` and then checking if `set.contains(b)` will return `false` even though the `Set` contains `a`, which is equal to `b`.

That's why the contract of `hashCode()` (in `Object` class) states that:

> If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.