# Hashing function in Hashtable vs. HashMap?

Tags: java, algorithm, hash, hashmap, hashtable

I know the difference between Hashtable and HashMap. However, both these classes seemingly are using a **hash function** to get the job done. Is there a difference between the hash function used in Hashtable, and the hash function used in HashMap?

In particular, is there a difference between the hashing algorithm they use? What is the formula used to hash in these two classes?

In other words, is the way for calculating index (hash value) different?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hash : How does it work internally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453476/hash-how-does-it-work-internally)

Comment: At the end, both are using `hashCode()` of the object beeing added to the collection. So, the algorithm to determine that "hash" depends on how YOU implemented `hashCode()` on the objects beeing added. (Or how its implemented on the object, in general)

Comment: Actually, for Java 8 the algorithms are (significantly) different; see my answer.

Comment: @Tibrogargan I don't think this is a duplicate of that question. At least I do not see my answer there.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> In particular, is there a difference between the hashing algorithm they use? What is the formula used to hash in these two classes?

The primary hash function used when you use an object as a hash table key is the object's `hashCode()` method.  It is up the to the key class to implement a decent hash function.

The `Hashtable` and `HashMap` classes take the key's hashcode value and convert it to an index in the primary hashtable array-of-chains.  However, there are differences in how this happens between `Hashtable` and `HashMap`.

- For `Hashtable` (Java 8) the code is this:

  ```
   hash = key.hashCode();
   index = (hash & 0x7FFFFFFF) % tab.length;
  ```
- For `HashMap` (Java 8) the code is (effectively) this:

  ```
   // (I have restructured the code for ease of comparison.)
   int h;
   hash = (key == null) ? 0 : (h = key.hashCode()) ^ (h >>> 16);
   index = (tab.length - 1) & hash;
  ```

As you can see, `HashMap` is scrambling the hashcode value returned by the key's hashcode function.  This is explained in the source code as follows:

> [This method] computes key.hashCode() and spreads (XORs) higher bits of hash to lower. Because the table uses power-of-two masking, sets of hashes that vary only in bits above the current mask will always collide. (Among known examples are sets of Float keys holding consecutive whole numbers in small tables.) So we apply a transform that spreads the impact of higher bits downward. There is a tradeoff between speed, utility, and quality of bit-spreading. Because many common sets of hashes are already reasonably distributed (so don't benefit from spreading), and because we use trees to handle large sets of collisions in bins, we just XOR some shifted bits in the cheapest possible way to reduce systematic lossage, as well as to incorporate impact of the highest bits that would otherwise never be used in index calculations because of table bounds.

Notes:

1. The `&` versus `%` difference is because in `Hashtable` the hash array size is a prime number, but in `HashMap` (Java 8) the size is a power of 2.
2. In Java 8 `HashMap`, the implementation will turn a long hash chain into a binary tree if the key class implements `Comparable`.
3. `HashMap` handles `null` keys, but `Hashtable` doesn't.

---

However, all of this extra complexity in `HashMap` only comes into play if your key class has a poorly designed / implemented `hashCode()` method ... or if someone is deliberately trying to engineer hash collisions.

In other words, if your key class is well designed, the differences *should not matter*.

Answer (score 2):

`java.util.Hashtable<K,V>` is like `java.util.Vector<T>`. It's a class added to the SDK very early in development which has been superseded by `HashMap<K,V>` (as `ArrayList<T>` superseded `Vector<T>`).

So you simply shouldn't use it unless you require implicit synchronization of all the operations, which comes by default with `Hashtable`, but you can stil use `Collections.synchronizedMap` for that purpose or a `ConcurrentHashMap<K,V>`.

As stated in Javadoc:

> As of the Java 2 platform v1.2, this class was retrofitted to implement the `Map` interface, making it a member of the Java Collections Framework. Unlike the new collection implementations, `Hashtable` is synchronized. If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, **it is recommended to use `HashMap` in place of `Hashtable`**. If a thread-safe highly-concurrent implementation is desired, then it is recommended to use `ConcurrentHashMap` in place of `Hashtable`.

The hashing of the two classes should be the same, as they'll both use `int Object::hashCode` for their purpose.

Comment: For example in ArrayList when the capacity is reached the size of the array is multiplied by 1.5; however, in Vector this ratio is 2. So, they are not totally the same.

Comment: That's not really important in any serious way.

Comment: @A.Mashreghi that's an implementation detail, why does it concern you?

Comment: Actually, for Java 8 the algorithms are (significantly) different; see my answer.

Comment: @A.Mashreghi - Arguably, that is not a difference in the hashing algorithm.  Rather it is a difference in the resizing algorithm.

Comment: @A.Mashreghi, I can see you have accepted wrong answer.Stephen C has given correct answer.

Comment: @StephenC  I was just giving an example of the case that the fact that some class supersedes another does not necessarily mean they have no implementation difference.

Comment: Yes, but it was a bad (i.e. not apropos) example.  Jack is clearly talking about "should be the same" with respect to the hashing algorithm.  (He's not correct though ...)